# How to save a variable in an rspec expect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have something along the following lines in one of my `spec` files:

```
expect(my_instance).to receive(:my_function).with(arg: instance_of(String))
```

I want to be able to capture the actual value of `arg` in a variable I can use in the spec. Is there a way to do that? I checked the rspec docs but didn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could declare the variable, say `captured_arg` before the `expect` (or `allow`, if you don't want it to fail if `my_instance` does not receive `my_function`). Then you can collect the arguments in a block and set `captured_arg` within that block.

```
captured_arg = nil
expect(my_instance).to receive(:my_function) { |arg| captured_arg = arg }
```

**Edit: (Keyword Arguments)**

If you are using [keyword arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments), just modify the script above slightly, using `arg` as the keyword argument you'd like to capture:

```
captured_arg = nil
expect(my_instance).to receive(:my_function) { |args| captured_arg = args[:arg] }
```